Is there a pytorch Implementation of CodeSearchNet
Is there a pytorch Implementation of CodeSearchNet?
I was trying to start a semantic code search task from code search net.
I was struggling to find code search net archive on huggingface but later I found the code search net was initially done on tensorflow 1.12 which was outdated.
I am hoping to find a code search net implementation of code search net baseline.
I only found this but it was also outdated as some package in requirements is not accessbiable " https://github.com/haseebs/semantic-code-search/blob/master/requirements.txt
I am hoping to find a code search net implementation of code search net baseline.
